# Conflicting types in flex on Linux - Windows ok

Tags: c, linux, flex-lexer

Some lines of my flex file:

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "types.h"


#define NO_YY_UNPUT
/* #define YY_NEVER_INTERACTIVE */

extern char *strdup(const char *);

short unsigned int yylineno = 1;

%}

{ID}                {
    yylval.txt = strdup(yytext);
    return ID;
};
\n                  { ++yylineno; }
```

My code looks good but I have problem when i want to compile on Ubuntu. In windows everything is okay but on linux I have errors like:

```
lex.l:10:14: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
lex.l:12:20: error: conflicting types for ‘yylineno’
lex.c:355:5: note: previous definition of ‘yylineno’ was here
```

Line 10: `extern char *strdup(const char *);`

Line 12: `short unsigned int yylineno = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strdup` is declared in `string.h`, but it is a Posix interface and you should define an appropriate feature test macro before including any system header:

```
%top {
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "types.h"
}
```

(Note: Using `%top` forces the enclosed code to be inserted at the top of the generated C file, in order to provide the guarantee that the feature test macro is defined before any system header.)

I don't know if that works on Windows (and it certainly depends on your compiler and toolchain), so you might need to declare `strdup` on that platform. If so, make sure you surround the declaration with a preprocessor test for the build environment.)

The error at line 10 is probably the result of `strdup` being defined as a macro. I'm not sure under what conditions that will happen -- it will be some GNU extension mode -- but defining the Posix feature test macro should prevent it.

As for the error with the type of `yylineno`, there is a simple solution: don't declare `yylineno`. It is declared in the code flex generates (and it may be declared as a macro if you ask for a re-entrant -- "pure" -- lexer).

Comment: without declaring `yylineno` program working good and without line with `strdup` as well... this is the best solution for me, but thank's for help! :)